# How i set page access token to make request with graph api in php sdk

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Sir i have a problem related to graph api with php sdk,i just want to make request from my php code to graph api getting page conversation here is my code

```
$request2 = new FacebookRequest(
$session,
'GET',
'/8499295645458',//page_id
array(
 'fields' => 'conversations'


  )
 );
```

Now i have a problem when we request from graph api then there is a page access token who make request,and i get results.but if i want to make request with php code where i put page access token.please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should user page access token session instead redirect access token in session variable like

```
$facebookSession = new FacebookSession($pageAccessToken);
```

and then use that in graph api request like,

```
$request2 = new FacebookRequest(
 $facebookSession,
 'GET',
  '/'.$pageID,
  array(
   'fields' => 'conversations'
  )
  );
```

that's it now make requests chill.